# Application crashes while creating persistent store when switching icloud account

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, icloud

I am implementing iCloud in my core data of application.
But the problem is that when i am switching iCloud account application crashes while adding persistent store. Following is the error log i am getting

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x1cd3c600 {NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/E7E99FZSXM~com~tpt~mobileinventorynavigator/data/.baseline/com.tpt.mobilecommoditytrader.store200hij/R374GT_SOtlsru2c6ZdIu7SJvDIGqlBCc9juS0aP_0k=/baseline.zip, NSUnderlyingError=0x1cd3d000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor"}
" UserInfo=0x1cd3d850 {NSLocalizedDescription=<PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x1cd3e4d0>(0)
    permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1cd3e320>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/E7E99FZSXM~com~tpt~mobileinventorynavigator/data/.baseline/com.tpt.mobilecommoditytrader.store200hij/R374GT_SOtlsru2c6ZdIu7SJvDIGqlBCc9juS0aP_0k=/baseline.zip
    safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1cd3da20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/E7E99FZSXM~com~tpt~mobileinventorynavigator/data/.baseline/com.tpt.mobilecommoditytrader.store200hij/R374GT_SOtlsru2c6ZdIu7SJvDIGqlBCc9juS0aP_0k=/mobile.CE450AC2-AB0D-5B69-BA2F-280ACE4DC4F5
    currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1cd3e320>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/E7E99FZSXM~com~tpt~mobileinventorynavigator/data/.baseline/com.tpt.mobilecommoditytrader.store200hij/R374GT_SOtlsru2c6ZdIu7SJvDIGqlBCc9juS0aP_0k=/baseline.zip

    storeName: com.tpt.mobilecommoditytrader.store200hij
    modelVersionHash: R374GT_SOtlsru2c6ZdIu7SJvDIGqlBCc9juS0aP_0k=
    baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1cd3e320>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/E7E99FZSXM~com~tpt~mobileinventorynavigator/data/.baseline/com.tpt.mobilecommoditytrader.store200hij/R374GT_SOtlsru2c6ZdIu7SJvDIGqlBCc9juS0aP_0k=/baseline.zip
```

I am also intercepting iCloud account changes and deleting store file and creating new one. But no success i got. Please suggest if you have any idea what's wrong i am doing

Comment: Are you putting the Core Data store file in the ubiquity container (somewhere relative to `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:`) or in the app sandbox (like in the Documents directory)?

Answer (score 0):

initially check weather you have login in icloud account or not which the following code

```
 NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                       URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

if(ubip== nil)  
     NSLOG(no icloud acount);  
else  
     NSLOG(icloud acount);
```

Comment: my problem is not with deleting and relogin to the same account!! but my problem is on switching multiple account on one device